# Sql Server Reporting Service 2010 WITH JAVA ee application

Tags: java, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to integrate Sql Server Reporting Service with Java EE application. 
I can see 2 reports on the reporting server. I am trying to use the RS web service to access the server. Steps taken by me are

1. Created Dynamic project in Eclipse
2. Got to New - Web Service client and entered the Web service defination as
         ://serverName:port/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl
3. I see in my project the below packages
   com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer
   com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer.holders

My code:

```
com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer.Reporting‌Service2010SoapProxy service = new com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer.ReportingSe‌​rvice2010SoapProxy();
String endPo="://serverName:port/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl";
service.setEndpoint(endPo);
service.logonUser("serverName\\username", "password",null );
```

The error is:

```
AxisFault faultCode: {xml.apache.org/axis}HTTP faultSubcode: faultString: (401)Unauthorized
```

After this I am not sure what I need to do. Please help me.
I also tried to consume this web service using a proxy but I am getting an error.
Kindly help me on what should be exactly done in order to consume SSRS 2010 webservice in Java.

Regards,
Neel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! re: "but I am getting an error" - please include the error and how you tried to consume the service.

Comment: @Tass:I created Proxy java class to consume the web service.code:
1.com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer.ReportingService2010SoapProxy service =   new  com.microsoft.schemas.sqlserver.reporting._2010._03._01.ReportServer.ReportingService2010SoapProxy();
 2. String endPo="://serverName:port/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl"; 
service.setEndpoint(endPo);
 3. Next service.logonUser("serverName\\username", "password",null );
Error I am getting is 
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (401)Unauthorized

Comment: Have a look how I've edited your question above, much easier to read the code this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've got incorrect authentication settings.

Your generated proxy is likely using HTTP Basic authentication, which by default isn't supported by reporting services. If you want to support it (if it's acceptable?) you need to enable the `RSWindowsBasic` authentication type.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx for the documentation on how to do so.

Ongoing, you'll need to research how to make your java proxy work with NTLM.

Comment: Hi Tass, Thanks for the clues , these clues helped me a lot... I am finally able to consume SSRS web service in Java.. thanks for your help...